Proof Angular Velocity is additive
If we have a sequence of time dependent reference frames and we want to compute the angular velocity of an object with respect to the first reference frame, my understanding is you transform each angular velocity into the coordinate system of the first reference frame then add them.
How can this be proved?

This question is similar to: Adding angular velocity vectors. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
